# Follow Up: PHP variables not appearing in sent email

Tags: php, forms, contacts

To start, i apologise for starting another question, but my update to my previous post ([Some PHP variables not appearing when contact us form is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862066/some-php-variables-not-appearing-when-contact-us-form-is-used)) was not responded to.

I made the suggestions as suggested in the previous post and uploaded the files to my hosting provider. However when i attempt to submit the contact form, a new error appears called "page save failed".

Below is the current php code:

```
<?php
if(!$_POST) exit;

$to       = 'enquiries@mydomain.com'; #Replace your email id...
$name     = $_POST['txtname'];
$email    = $_POST['txtemail'];
$phone    = $_POST['txtphone'];
$comp     = $_POST['txtcomp'];
$emp      = $_POST['txtemp'];
$move     = $_POST['txtmove'];
$comment  = $_POST['txtmessage'];

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { $comment = stripslashes($comment); }


 $subject = 'Office enquiry from ' . $name . '.';

 $msg  = "You have been contacted by ".$name."\r\n\n";
 $msg .= "You can contact ".$name." via email, ".$email.".\r\n\n";
 $msg .= "You can call ".$name." on ".$phone.".\r\n\n";
 $msg .= "$name has ".$emp." employees and the company name is ."$comp.".\r\n\n";
 $msg .= $name." would like to move in on ."$move.".\r\n\n";
 $msg .= $comment."\r\n\n";


 $msg .= "---------------------------------------------------------------\r\n";

 if(@mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n"))
 {
     echo "<span class='success-msg'>Thanks for Contacting Us, We have received your query and will be in touch soon.</span>";
 }
 else
 {
     echo "<span class='error-msg'>Sorry your message was not sent, Please try again or contact us via live chat.</span>";
 }
 ?>
```

Once again sorry for starting a new question, but i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have some erros in your string concatenation:

Replace this part:

```
 $msg .= "$name has ".$emp." employees and the company name is ."$comp.".\r\n\n";
 $msg .= $name." would like to move in on ."$move.".\r\n\n";
```

To this:

```
 $msg .= "$name has ". $emp ." employees and the company name is" . "$comp" . "\r\n\n";
 $msg .= $name." would like to move in on " . $move . "\r\n\n";
```

Besides, try to avoid the use of `@` to suppress the warnings. Without it, you'll able to see any error of the `mail()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i will try it now.